# I want to create a function that takes an array containing only numbers and return the larger

Tags: numbers, constants, splice

const numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const numbers 2 = numbers.splice (1,4)

console.log (numbers);

Trying how to accurately access the 2nd element in the array.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are trying to access the largest number in the array or the number at the second index of the array?

Comment: to access the second element of the array

Comment: The [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) class is index-accessible starting at index `0`. You can just use `numbers[1]` to access the second element (at the index `1`).